# Best Way to Find the Array Contains a Given String

Tags: c++, arrays, string, performance, classification

I have some arrays of strings and a function that gets a string and return the type of it (the array that the string belongs to)

How can I do it with the best speed?

```
string arr1[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
string arr2[] = {"d", "e", "f"};
string arr3[] = {"g", "h", "i"};
string arr4[] = {"j", "k", "l"};

...
string getFamily(string input)
{
if(arr1.contains(input)
return "TYPE_1";
...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Reading about [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) should be a good start.

Comment: I forget to say that I don't want to do this with lots of if else. because I have a lot of arrays.

Comment: Does it have to be a function or can you have a class instantiated?

Comment: No every good methods is fine. I just want to get the family of string in one step. I don't want to put if, else if for all families.

Comment: Then collect your arrays in an array, and loop over the arrays? An alternative to `std::find` if (and only if) each of the arrays is sorted is to use [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search). And there is no way in standard C++ to search multiple arrays at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not elegant, but if you want fast, you can make a prepared unordered_map to do the search which would be useful if this function will be called 100s of times (wasteful if rarely called).  Ideally, you can make this container in a class object rather than a global variable and the return type an integral value rather than a string.  This would produce a search of O(1) with the cost being in the hashing of the key.  But I do not know enough of your requirements.

If you would rather call once, then do as Joachim Pileborg suggested and do a series of std::find calls until you get a hit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string > g_map;

std::string arr1[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
std::string arr2[] = {"d", "e", "f"};
std::string arr3[] = {"g", "h", "i"};
std::string arr4[] = {"j", "k", "l"};

const char * map_value( const std::string & input )
{
    std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string >::iterator iter( g_map.find( input ) );
    return iter == g_map.end() ? "NOT FOUND" : iter->second.c_str();
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    // Build the map;
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof( arr1 ) / sizeof( std::string ); ++i )
        g_map[arr1[i]] = "TYPE_1";
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof( arr2 ) / sizeof( std::string ); ++i )
        g_map[arr2[i]] = "TYPE_2";
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof( arr3 ) / sizeof( std::string ); ++i )
        g_map[arr3[i]] = "TYPE_3";
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof( arr4 ) / sizeof( std::string ); ++i )
        g_map[arr4[i]] = "TYPE_4";

    std::string input;
    std::cout << map_value( "b" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << map_value( "z" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << map_value( "eb" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << map_value( "j" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << map_value( "f" ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
TYPE_1
NOT FOUND
NOT FOUND
TYPE_4
TYPE_2
```